# Am I opening my database the right way?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a DatabaseManager class that handles creating and opening the DB in my app, and handing out the 'context' when it's needed.  The problem is that `openWithCompletionHandler` is async, so the openDatabase call returns immediately then my initial view controller crashes trying to get data from a database that's not done opening.

My solution is to pass the initial VC to the openDatabase method and have it call back into my VC from within the completion handler code block.  So my initial VC basically calls to the DatabaseManager to open the database then sits and waits until it gets a call back, then gets the data it needs for the display.

It works fine and there is no perceptible delay in the data appearing.

Is this the normal way to do it?  I'd like to learn the best way rather than jury rigging something that works.  I tried a variety of searches and reading Apple docs and couldn't find the answer.  If I missed something obvious in the docs, please point me there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is this the normal way to do it?" Yes. That's what you do when something is asynchronous. There is a complication because object A that does the asynchronous thing isn't object B that needs to reload its data when the asynchronous thing is done, but you've solved that beautifully by handing across a reference to object A. This is really no different from e.g. NSURLSession calling back its delegate.

Comment: You're very welcome. There are possible refinements where the asynchronous process doesn't need to know anything about the main object (its class or its methods). For example, you could use a protocol and a true delegate architecture; or instead of handing across a reference to self, you could hand across an Objective-C block. But there's nothing whatever wrong with what you're doing.